# How to run a function on the pressed List.item only without it running on all the other List.item in the array. (React Native, Expo)

Tags: react-native, expo, react-native-paper

So I am rendering a list of List.Accordion like this. Each Accordion represents a person and each list.item is a button that gives the user the option to perform an action(function).

```
<List.Section title="User List" titleStyle={{ fontWeight: "bold" }}>
            {displayUser != [] &&
              displayUser.map((item) => {
                return (
                  <List.Accordion
                    title={item.email}
                    titleStyle={styles.userItem}
                  >
                    <List.Item
                      title="Ban"
                      left={(props) => (
                        <MaterialCommunityIcons
                          {...props}
                          name="cancel"
                          size="15"
                        />
                      )}
                      titleStyle={styles.itemText}
                      onPress={() => banUser(item.id)}
                    />
                  </List.Accordion>
                );
              })}
          </List.Section>
```

I wanted the banUser function to run only once for the corresponding person (the pressed List.item). But when it is pressed, it is also run in every other List.item in every other List.accordions. How do I fix this? Please help.

I tried using useEffect? but it did not seem to work.

Comment: You likely have your map at the wrong level, it should be inside the List.Accordion. Still, your callback shouldn't run for each component. How do you know that's happening?

Comment: `displayUser != []` will always be true since its checking for a reference. You should check for `displayUser.length > 0`

Answer (score 0):

Is this "**in every other List.accordions**" was in other component also? if Yes, you need to use state management and **useEffect**, usually I use **redux** to trigger some function to refresh all list if some data is deleted.

```
useEffect(() => {
// function to reload all accordion user
}, [user.refreshUser]);
```

You need to add useEffect function and use **user.refreshUser** as trigger to reload the list.